# How to dynamically generate multiple input fields jQuery without overriding the last one

Tags: jquery, variables, loops, dynamic, foreach

So I'm working on some jQuery code to get new phone data displayed on the page.

So far everything is working except that the last phone number is the only one to be displayed no matter how many phone numbers I have. I discovered that it's because my `$('.new_option').append(inputphone);` is overriding the last one.

**Here is the jsFiddle** (not exactly the same code since I don't have a database Object, but produces the same problem): http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/dvYMb/

The Variable (HTML with label + input):

```
var inputphone = $("<li><label></label><br/><input type='tel' pattern='[0-9]{10}' class='added_phone' name='' value='' autocomplete='off' maxlength='20' /></li>");
```

HTML DOM:

```
<li>
    <ul class="new_option">
    </ul>
</li>
```

The each loop:

```
$(profileData.phones).each(function(i) {
    console.log(' ');
    console.log('Phones: '+i);
    console.log(profileData.phones[i].label);
    $('.new_option').append(inputphone); //<-- The Issue
    $('.added_phone').parent().find('label').text(profileData.phones[i].tag);
    $('.added_phone').attr('id', "added_"+profileData.phones[i].tag+"phone" + i);
    $('.added_phone').attr('value', profileData.phones[i].label);
});
```

Console:
[image]

Result on page:
[image]

My question is how do I make this line dynamically generate new fields with unique id's?

```
$('.new_option').append(inputphone);
```

Searching around [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500228/javascript-dynamically-pushing-objects-into-an-array-not-working-in-firefox-ie) I see people saying use an object, but haven't been successful with that approach yet.

How would you handle this?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle to show us it working?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle I just created: http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/dvYMb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from a forum poster at [CSS-Tricks Javascript form post](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/dynamically-generated-input-is-getting-overriding-by-previous-input/)

CodePen http://codepen.io/ggilmore/pen/f3a88dd68a7b1d101712b75318925198

```
var inputphone = "<label></label><br/><input type='tel' pattern='[0-9]{10}' class='added_phone' name='' value='' autocomplete='off' maxlength='20' />";

var profileData = "Text for input";
var currentListItem;

for (var i = 0, max = 2; i < max; i++) {
    $('.new_option').append('<li class="input-'+i+'" />');

    currentListItem = $('.input-'+i);
    currentListItem
        .append(inputphone)
        .find('label').text(profileData)

    currentListItem
        .find('.added_phone').attr('id', "added_phone" + i).attr('value', profileData);
}
```

Also note: This works for my simple basic example I created in jsFiddle and CodePen, however upon further developing it was still causing the same issue with my phoneData object.

So going a different route. Getting the phone numbers to be displayed via Python(which I should have done in the first place, the front-end developer in me loves jQuery however) I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused because you fill up the ul and don't reset it after.

Here's what you need to do:

```
$(profileData.phones).each(function(i) {
    console.log(' ');
    console.log('Phones: '+i);
    console.log(profileData.phones[i].label);
    $('.new_option').append(inputphone);
    // Reset the ul now and add a new empty ul
    $('.new_option').attr('class', 'ul_added');
    var p = $('.added_phone').parent().parent(); // This is the li above the ul
    p.append('<ul class="new_option"></ul>');
    // Set the values
    $('.added_phone').parent().find('label').text(profileData.phones[i].tag);
    $('.added_phone').attr('id', "added_"+profileData.phones[i].tag+"phone" + i);
    $('.added_phone').attr('value', profileData.phones[i].label);
});
```

Comment: Hmm I thought this would work, but it creates a new ul, however doesn't target it to put in new content? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/Fv3NX/

Comment: Ugh, the problem is that the DOM state prior to the call to $.each will be maintained in each pass. So when we end up changing 2 times, it's only the second change that takes effect.

We could probably use classic JS functions like createElement to make this work.